# How to convert CorelDraw svg to Google maps compatible icon?

Tags: google-maps, svg, coreldraw

i have this type svg file which i made with corelDraw,

```
<metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
      <path class="fil0" d="M8572 6162c3284,1827 5559,4582 6491,8573 -3880,482 -7761,964 -11641,1446 1355,-1726 5125,-8208 4798,-10151 -941,235 -2058,532 -2999,767 1023,-776 2117,-1640 3140,-2416 64,3596 97,7263 -71,10812 917,-2496 871,-5594 282,-9031z"/>
      <path class="fil0" d="M2125 16843c135,512 594,922 1270,1129 3563,-71 7109,0 10672,-71 1513,-371 2379,-1357 2998,-2575 -4939,552 -10001,964 -14940,1517z"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

and i need to covert it to google maps icon svg. It look like Google uses the different format, for example

```
M -1.1500216e-4,0 C 0.281648,0 0.547084,-0.13447 0.718801,-0.36481 l 17.093151,-22.89064 c 0.125766,-0.16746 0.188044,-0.36854 0.188044,-0.56899 0,-0.19797 -0.06107,-0.39532 -0.182601,-0.56215 -0.245484,-0.33555 -0.678404,-0.46068 -1.057513,-0.30629 l -11.318243,4.60303 0,-26.97635 C 5.441639,-47.58228 5.035926,-48 4.534681,-48 l -9.06959,0 c -0.501246,0 -0.906959,0.41772 -0.906959,0.9338 l 0,26.97635 -11.317637,-4.60303 c -0.379109,-0.15439 -0.812031,-0.0286 -1.057515,0.30629 -0.245483,0.33492 -0.244275,0.79809 0.0055,1.13114 L -0.718973,-0.36481 C -0.547255,-0.13509 -0.281818,0 -5.7002158e-5,0 Z
```

As you see it looks pretty different. And with my SVG i can not use icon "rotate" property.
Thanks.

Comment: Um, the part in the `d=""` is an svg path, as is the part you quote from google.  What if you provide `M8572 6162c3284,1827 5559,4582 6491,8573 -3880,482 -7761,964 -11641,1446 1355,-1726 5125,-8208 4798,-10151 -941,235 -2058,532 -2999,767 1023,-776 2117,-1640 3140,-2416 64,3596 97,7263 -71,10812 917,-2496 871,-5594 282,-9031z` to the google API?  (note that the corel draw SVG has two paths in it)